# Jquery Masonry and Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, masonry

I've used Dylan Baumann's GitHub repository for integrating Masonry and Foundation. It worked great in Foundation 3, but not so well in Foundation 5. On both F3 and F5 I get images stacking vertically.

For F3, I used the following JS to resize the window and stop the images stacking vertically:

```
$(".title").click(function () {
  $(window).trigger('resize');
```

});

But that does not work in F5 with the following (Masonry is within a Foundation Accordion element):

```
<script>
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        isFitWidth: true
    }); 
});
$("#secondary div.row div.small-12.large-9.columns dl.accordion dd.accordion-navigation a").on("click", function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize'); 
});
```

The markup changed for the Accordion element in F5, so the window resize target changed. I've tried many different methods, but can't get it to work.

[The site in question is here](http://solborg.fhs.no/adventure/) - need to click on "Bilder far Adventure".

Anyone found a solution to the images stacking problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. Use `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))` instead of window resize:

```
$("dd.accordion-navigation a").on("click", function () {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))
});
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a content site project using Jekyll and as I was doing my research I came up with a possible answer:

I suggest you to do it [The Zurb Way](http://zurb.com/university/lessons/make-a-masonry-grid-responsive)